# How to set a viewmodel property if a listbox item selected?

Tags: wpf, properties, viewmodel, listboxitem, selected

I have a listbox...and it is bound to list of items of type (class) "A". Class "A" has a boolean property "IsCurrentViewActive". This is false by default. When user select an item in listbox....i need to set the "IsCurrentViewActive" property of corresponding item to TRUE.

I tried the below code in my listbox...but it is not working..Any help would be appreciated.

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemTabStyle2Extended" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" >
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsCurrentViewActive, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsCurrentViewActive, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </DataTrigger>                    
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
```

**EDIT :  Can we do this way or Do I need to use attached property ?**

Comment: The style looks correct.  Where is this style placed? Inside <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle> block of ListBox or as a resource somewhere.

Comment: style is in a resource ...and i access it in ListBox tag ..as follows...ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemTabStyle2Extended}"

Comment: When the Application load, the property is set for first item...But when I click the second item...it is not setting the property.

Comment: How is "IsCurrentViewActive" implemented? Is it a plain .NET property or a dependency property? If it's set the first time, then I am suspicious that you have a plain .NET property and you haven't implemented INotifyProperty changed for it.

Comment: @MattBurland I thought the same thing except that he wants IsSelected(target) to update IsCurrentViewActive(source) so its effectively a OneWayToSource binding - so normally that shouldn't need RaisePropertyChanged on IsCurrentViewActive? Not 100% sure about that - you might be right it could be required.

Comment: i have inotify in that..in the listbox there are multiple items...When user load app, first item will be selected...in that case...that viewmodel's IsCurrentView property is set to true...but when user select second item...it's viewmodel property is not setting true...So iut's not issue with notifying

Comment: Typically I would rather bound ListBox.SelectedItem (or index) property to some CLR property. It may be more comfortable for later usage.

Comment: Perhaps it would be useful to post the code for the view model in question.

Answer (score 0):

The above XAML worked fine for me actually. I think it's just a matter of getting the context right. I have created a sample that you can download where this works fine. I think the difference might be that in my version, I store the style in ListBox's parent control's resources. I don't think you can store them in the ListBox's resources.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/s64kp9p0b2w1imk/ListBoxMenu.7z?dl=0